# JQuery SimpleModal popup opens only once per page (firefox)

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using Eric Martins [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) JQuery plugin to display nice and simple modal popups.

However I've run into the problem recently where I am unable to open up any popup more than once per page. I have 3+ different buttons to open different modal popups all over the page. They all close nicely after I'm done with them, but then I can't open another without reloading the page. All popups individually work fine. I also get no javascript errors when I click on the links that are supposed to open the new popup.

I've debug step through'ed the javascript with Firebug in FireFox, but that didn't give me a clue either. It gets to the click() handler just fine it just doesn't actually show the popup.

Also, I've tried my page with every other browser i have on my machine (Latest versions of: IE8, Opera, Chrome and Safari) and it all works perfectly there.

To further investigate this I created a new MVC3 project and only added a link and jqueried a modal popup on the click, and that does work in firefox too. So basically I'm all out of things to look at, and am hoping someone here can give me a pointer.

The code I use to call the popups:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.editwidget').click(function (e) {
        var splitIndex = $(this).attr('id').indexOf('_');
        var pageWidgetId = $(this).attr('id').substring(splitIndex + 1);
        var src = '/Edit/@Model.Name/Widgets/' + pageWidgetId;
        $.modal('<iframe frameborder="0" src="' + src + '" style="border:0px;width:100%;height:490px;" />',{
            containerCss:
            {
                height: "500px",
                width: "620px",
                padding: "5px"
            },
            overlayClose: true,
            onClose: $.modal.close()
            });
            });

</script>
```

My firefox version is 3.6.14

I hope someone can help!

Thank you for reading.

-- edit -- 
I am fairly sure that this worked before today, and this morning my firefox crashed for no apparent reason and shoved this 3.6.14 update down my throat. I'm tempted to just blame firefox. And I'm only fairly sure too because I changed some stuff before I noticed it wasn't working. But since it is working perfectly in every other browser, it doesn't look good for the 'fox ...

-- edit number 2 --
I think I was right in blaming firefox. a full reboot of my PC made everything work as it should again. Now how to I close my own question? Yes I'm very new to actually posting on StackOverflow :)

Comment: You want to open multiple popup at the same time ?

Comment: Try adding parameter `appendTo: '#aspnetForm'` to $.modal.

Comment: @alexl No not multiple at the same time. Each one is a proper 'modal' popup. Just pops up with an iframe and then closes to show the page again. After that I want it to be possible to open another (or the same) popup again though!

Comment: @jamietre I am using ASP.Net MVC3 so no #aspnetForm for me! I'll try specifying the body <div> to make sure it's in the right place.

Comment: Odd. I use simplemodal a lot and it's always been nice to me, and don't see anything clearly amiss here. I usually use an existing hidden div as the source, though. I can think of no reason that would matter, but maybe try that for fun. Other than that, I would just trace the js code execution in a debugger and see where simplemodal is bailing out.

Comment: One other thought, you have `onClose: $.modal.close()`. That argument is supposed to be an anonymous function, and if all you're doing is calling close, it's not needed, as that is the default behavior. Maybe close() is not getting called because of they way you're binding to that parameter. Seems like this must have something to do with cleanup since it works once.

Answer (score 0):

try using another modal. Something like [Facebox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: That's a really pretty modal plugin! But after playing with it for 20 minutes I didn't get it to work as well as I have the simplemodal. Which for some reason unknown to me started working as expected again. Maybe it got jealous that I tried out a different plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with my jquery ui dialog. When i close it (X-it), firefox 3.6.14 is not responding for a bit than it close everything. Everything works well in other browser and it is still working on my other computer with 3.6.13.

I will try to reboot and see...

Nope still have the problem only in FF 3.6.14

Answer (score -1):

Rebooted my PC and now everything works as it should ... FireFox was just having a difficult period ...